# Check a string for alphabetically ordered characters

Tags: php, string

This seems so obvious , but I cannot find a way to do this.
I think there even is a regular PHP function to do this, but even that one stays well hidden after 1,5 hours of intensive Google searches.

## What I want

- A function that takes a string as input.
- Checks that string for the number of times it has alphabetical orderded sequences of more than 3 characters:
- returns true if a sequence of more than 3 has been found.

## Example

**"youlookgreatbcdetoday"** =>  has "bcde" in it ... so has to return true
**"youlookgreatklmtoday"**  =>  only has "klm" in it ... so that has to return false
**"youlookgreattoday"**     =>  has no alphabetically ordered sequences in it, so returns false

## Possible usecase

- password strength checker
- wordgame
- ...

***disclaimer:** I wish I already had some code to show you, but I literally have nothing yet.
Only thing I could come up with was to split the string up in an array and do some magic on the array ... but even then I got stuck.*

Hope one of you will save me :)

Comment: Hey that's programming, and it's much more fun than googling the solution. Why not start with the first character and check if the next is in order and the next too? If not, then proceed with the second and so on. You can get a character of a string with $string[$index].

Comment: OK, does `yzab` count as a sequence?

Comment: @martinstoeckli I voted your answer up cause indeed, looking for answers on Google is a poormans solution. Should have posted what I had so far , but didn't want to make a fool of myself :D

Comment: @SalmanA that's a good remark (didn't even think of that). The answer should be 'yes' > "yzab" counts as a sequence too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, let's start off with a trivial implementation using a loop and a counter (for increasing only):

```
function hasOrderedCharactersForward($string, $num = 4) {
    $len = strlen($string);
    $count = 0;
    $last = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $current = ord($string[$i]);
        if ($current == $last + 1) {
            $count++;
            if ($count >= $num) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $count = 1;
        }
        $last = $current;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, how does it work? Basically, it loops through, and checks to see if the `ord` (ascii number) of the character is one more than the one before it. If so, it increases the count parameter. Otherwise, it sets it to 1 (since we already processed that character). Then, if `$count` is ever more or equal to the number requested, we know we found a sequence, and can return...

So, now let's check in both directions:

```
function hasOrderedCharacters($string, $num = 4) {
    $len = strlen($string);
    $count = 0;
    $dir = 1;
    $last = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $current = ord($string[$i]);
        if ($count == 1 && $current == $last - 1) {
            $count++;
            $dir = -1;
            if ($count >= $num) {
                return true;
            }
        } elseif ($current == $last + $dir) {
            $count++;
            if ($count >= $num) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $count = 1;
            $dir = 1;
        }
        $last = $current;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, it'll return true for `abcd` and `dcba`...

Now, here's a far simpler solution:

```
function hasOrderedCharactersForward($string, $num = 4) {
    $len = strlen($string) + 1;
    $array = array_map(
        function($m) use (&$len) {
            return ord($m[0]) + $len--;
        }, 
        str_split($string, 1)
    );
    $str = implode('_', $array);
    $regex = '#(^|_)(\d+)' . str_repeat('_\2', $num - 1) . '(_|$)#';
    return (bool) preg_match($regex, $str);
}
```

And there you go. We use the property that if we add a decreasing number to each position, consecutive sequences will appear as the same number. And that's exactly how this works.

And here's the same theory applied to both directions:

```
function hasOrderedCharacters($string, $num = 4) {
    $i = 0;
    $j = strlen($string);
    $str = implode('', array_map(function($m) use (&$i, &$j) {
        return chr((ord($m[0]) + $j--) % 256) . chr((ord($m[0]) + $i++) % 256);
    }, str_split($string, 1)));
    return preg_match('#(.)(.\1){' . ($num - 1) . '}#', $str);
}
```

Comment: thumbs up for the both directions angle (did not even think of that -> not good). Function seems to work perfectly.

Comment: so many good answers, it's hard to pick just one but I guess yours was good cause 1) you thought about the reverse angle (which I did not even think about) and 2) you also went out of your way to explain the function + work on it some more to optimize it. Thanx again. and thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
function check($input, $length = 4)
{
    $sequence = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $sequence .= substr($sequence, 0, $length - 1);
    // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz is converted to abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($sequence) - $length; $i++) {
        // loop runs for $i = 0...25
        if (strpos($input, substr($sequence, $i, $length)) !== false) {
            echo sprintf('"%s" contains "%s"' . PHP_EOL, $input, substr($sequence, $i, $length));
            return true;
        }
    }
    echo sprintf('"%s" is OK' . PHP_EOL, $input);
    return false;
}
check("youlookgreatbcdetoday"); // "youlookgreatbcdetoday" contains "bcde"
check("youlookgreatklmtoday");  // "youlookgreatklmtoday" is OK
check("youlookgreattoday");     // "youlookgreattoday" is OK
check("youlookgreattodayza");   // "youlookgreattodayza" is OK
check("youlookgreattodayzab");  // "youlookgreattodayzab" contains "yzab"
```

Answer (score 4):

Fewer loop and if condition!

```
  function alphacheck($str, $i=4)
  {
      $alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      $len = strlen($str);

      for($j=0; $j <= $len - $i; $j++){
          if(strrpos($alpha, substr($str, $j, $i)) !== false){
              return true;
          }
      }

      return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
/**
 * @param string $input Input string
 * @param int $length Length of required sequence
 *
 * @return bool
 */

function look_for_sequence($input, $length) {
    //If length of sequence is larger than input string, no sequence is possible.
    if ($length > strlen($input)) {
        return false;
    }
    //Normalize string, only lowercase
    //(That's because character codes for lowercase and uppercase are different).
    $input = strtolower($input);

    //We loop until $length characters before the end of the string, because after that,
    //No match can be found.
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input) - $length; $i++) {
        //Reset sequence counter
        $sequence = 1;
        //Character under inspection.
        $current_character = ord($input[$i]);
        //Let's look forward, $length characters forward:
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $i + $length; $j++) {
            $next_character = ord($input[$j]);
            //If this next character is actually the sequencing character after the current
            if ($next_character == $current_character+1) {
                //Increase sequence counter
                $sequence++;
                //Reset the current character, and move to the next
                $current_character = $next_character;
                //If $length characters of sequence is found, return true.
                if ($sequence >= $length) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            //If the next character is no sequencing,
            //break this inner loop and continue to the next character.
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(look_for_sequence("youlookgreatbcdetoday", 4));
```

Worked on any string I threw at it, and you also get to pick how many characters you want to count! Yey!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using PHP's [`ord()`](http://php.net/ord) to get each character's ASCII value and iterate through your string character-by-character comparing each value to find the sequences.

This may help:

```
function checkForSequences($str, $minSequenceLength = 4) {
    $length = strlen($str);
    $sequenceLength = 1;
    $reverseSequenceLength = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $currChar = ord(strtolower($str[$i]));
        $prevChar = ord(strtolower($str[$i - 1])) + 1;
        if ($currChar == $prevChar) {
            // we have two-letters back to back; increment the counter!
            $sequenceLength++;
            if ($sequenceLength == $minSequenceLength) {
                // we've reached our threshold!
                return true;
            }
            // reset the reverse-counter
            $reverseSequenceLength = 1;
        } else if ($currChar == ($prevChar - 2)) {
            // we have two-letters back to back, in reverse order; increment the counter!
            $reverseSequenceLength++;
            if ($reverseSequenceLength == $minSequenceLength) {
                // we've reached our threshold!
                return true;
            }
            // reset the forward-counter
            $sequenceLength = 1;
        } else {
            // no sequence; reset counter
            $sequenceLength = 1;
            $reverseSequenceLength = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What this function will do is, it will iterate through the string character by character. It will use `ord()` to get the current character's ASCII value and compare it to the *previous* character's ASCII value. If they are in sequence, either forward-or-reverse, it increments a counter. When the counter hit's `4`, it returns `true`!.

This will match forward and reverse sequence, as well as ignore case. So, `abcd` will match, `aBcD` will, and also `DcBa`, among any others!

Comment: But then you skip letters if a partial sequence is found.

Comment: @Truth Not sure I understand? Wasn't the OP's question for a function that would find any sequence with more-than-3 characters that are in-order and only return `true`/`false`? My answer returns `true` on the very first sequence of more-than-3 it finds; if none is found, it returns false. Please explain?

Comment: @newfurniturey thanks so much for that! Only thing is (might be me). if I do var_dump(checkForSequences("youlookgreatdcbatoday",4)); I get false (notice the "dcba" reverse sequence) -> altho reverse sequencing was not in my original question. Seems to work perfectly on regular order tho

Comment: @newfurniturey thanx for the update. Feel like an idiot for bothering you again tho > still returns false for the reverse order var_dump(checkForSequences("youlookgreatdcbatoday",4));   :/

Comment: @belgianwolfie Face, meet palm! Logic issue on my end again, it was supposed to be `- 2` (not 1) because I increment it in the beginning. Updated, and tested this time too!

Comment: @newfurniturey tested it too as soon as I saw you update it :D works perfectly now ! thanx so much for putting in your time.

Comment: @belgianwolfie No problem! I hope my answer, or even just the idea, can help you solve your question =]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution I came up with:

```
function alphaCheck($str){
    $array=str_split(strtolower($str));
    $minMatchLength=3;
    $check=array(ord($array[0]));
    foreach($array as $letter){
        $ascii=ord($letter);
        if($ascii==end($check)+1){
            $check[]=$ascii;
            if(count($check)==$minMatchLength)
                return true;
        }else{
            unset($check);
            $check=array($ascii);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$str="abcdhello";
$str2="testing";
$str3="abdcefghi";
if(alphaCheck($str))
    echo"STR GOOD";
if(alphaCheck($str2))
    echo "STR2 GOOD";
if(alphaCheck($str3))
    echo "STR3 GOOD";
```

Output is STR GOOD and STR3 GOOD.  `$minMatchLength` is the number of characters in a row that have to be in order for the function to return true. ("testing" has "st", but length is 3, so it returns false.

**EDIT**
I updated it to also check for "AbCdE" as just `ord` alone will not work for this.

Answer (score 1):

inequality comparison of characters does implicitly use the ord() value. Here's a simple script, which can be tweaked (particularly for case insensitivity):

```
<?php
$string = "thisabcdef";

function hasSequence($string, $sequence_length = 3) {
        $num_in_order = 0;
        for($i = 1; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
                if($string[$i] > $string[$i-1]) {
                        $num_in_order++;
                } else {
                        $num_in_order = 0;
                }
                if($num_in_order >= $sequence_length) {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }
        return FALSE;
}
if(hasSequence("testabcd")) {
        echo "YUP";
} else {
        echo "NOPE";
}
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simplistic? If you want case-insensitive, you could use `stripos()` instead.

```
function abc($test, $depth) {
    $alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $matches = 0;
    $length = strlen($test);

    while ($length--) {
        $char = substr($test, $length, $depth);

        if (strlen($char) == $depth && strpos($alpha, $char) !== false) {
            $matches++;
        }

        if ($matches == $depth) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

http://codepad.org/tIySKnm4

And (stealing IRCMaxwell's observation) with `strrev()`:

```
function abc($test, $depth) {
    $alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $matches = 0;
    $length = strlen($test);

    while ($length--) {
        $char = substr($test, $length, $depth);

        if (strlen($char) == $depth && 
            (strpos($alpha, $char) !== false || 
             strpos(strrev($alpha), $char) !== false)) {
            $matches++;
        }

        if ($matches == $depth) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

http://codepad.org/sjzrVAAg

Comment: Damn , gonna have a hard time picking accepted answer :/ thanks so much. works perfectly

Comment: What I like about this is it's pretty straight-forward and fairly self-explanatory. There are probably some ways to make it more efficient, such as check the `$test` length and toggle if longer than `$alpha` as that could be faster for long strings. Also, the `if ($matches...)` part could be put in the previous `if` so it's not checked each time... And if `$test` is shorter than `$depth`, return right away.

Answer (score 1):

It's also trivial to do with a [regular expression](http://regexp.info/):

```
preg_match('/  ((?=ab|bc|cd|de|ef|fg|gh).)  {2,}  /smix', "testabc")
```

You obviously need to complete the list of successive letters. And `{2,}` simply probes for a minimum of three letters in a range.

Comment: [Insert obligatory *regex is wrong and puppy murder* here.] `;)` I figured there was probably a way to do that like that (I'm not a regex'r though).

Comment: It takes a certain degree of evilness and determination to wrongdoing though.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take:

```
function checkConsecutiveness($string, $length = 3)
{

    $tempCount = 1; 

    for($i = 0; $i < count($tokens = str_split(strtolower($string)) ); $i++)
    {

        // if current char is not alphabetic or different from the next one, reset counter
        if(
            ord($tokens[$i]) < 97 ||
            ord($tokens[$i]) > 122 ||
            ord($tokens[$i]) != (ord( $tokens[$i+1]) -1)
        ){

            $tempCount = 1;

        }
        // else if we met given length, return true
        else if(++$tempCount >= $length)

            return true;

    }

    // no condition met by default
    return false;

}
```

It checks `$string` against any sequence of `$length` consecutive letters.

```
checkConsecutiveness('1@abcde1', 5) // returns true;
checkConsecutiveness('1@abcd1', 5) // returns false;
```

Mind to be sure current char is in 97-122 range, because the tick `[[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) #96] and the open curly brace { [ASCII #123] could lead to a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (the ASCII codes are in order with the alphabet):

```
function check_str_for_sequences($str, $min = 3) {
        $last_char_code = -1;
        $total_correct = 0;
        $str = strtolower($str);

        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
            //next letter in the alphabet from last char?
            if(ord($str[$i]) == ($last_char_code + 1)) {
                $total_correct++;

                //min sequence reached?
                if($total_correct >= ($min - 1)) {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            } else {
                $total_correct = 0;
            }

            $last_char_code = ord($str[$i]);
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

Usage:

```
$test = 'Lorem ipsum dolor abcsit amet';

echo '----->' . check_str_for_alpha($test); // ----->1
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
function countOrderedCharacters($str, $count){
    $matches = array();
    preg_replace_callback('/(?=(\w{'.$count.'}))/',function($x) use(&$matches,$count) {
        $seq = $x[1];
        if($count === 1){
            $matches[] = $seq;
            return;
        }
        $dif = ord($seq[1]) - ord($seq[0]);
        if (abs($dif)!=1) return;
        for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($seq)-1 ; $i++){
            if(ord($seq[$i+1]) - ord($seq[$i]) != $dif) return;
        }
        $matches[] = $seq;

    }, $str);
    return $matches;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this function :

```
function checkForString($string,$l=4){
   $length = strlen($string);
   $result = 0;
   for($i=0;$i<$length-1 && $result<4;$i++){

   if($string[$i+1] == $string[$i]++) $result++;

}
if($result>=4) return true;
else return false;
}
```